# If $|a|\le1,|b|\le1,|c|\le1,|b-a|\le|c-a|$ then show that $\frac{|b-c||b-a|}{|2c-b-a|}\le1$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, triangles

> If  $|a|\le1$,$|b|\le1$,$|c|\le1$ and $|b-a|\le|c-a|$ 
>   then show that $$\frac{|b-c||b-a|}{|2c-b-a|}\le1,$$ where $\{a,b,c\}\subset \mathbb{C}.$

This complex inequality is true, I am not able to prove it. I tried a lot of different approaches if there is any way you can think to solve this, it would help a lot.

Comment: If $2c = a+b$ (which is possible within the other conditions, e.g. any suitable $a=b=c$) the statement becomes undefined. Unless you're happy to define $\frac{0}{0}=1$. Why not more simply rewrite it multiplied through by the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(a)$, $B(b)$ and $C(c)$ in the Gauss plain.

Also, let $AB=z$, $AC=y$, $BC=x$, $M$ be a midpoint of $AB$

and $R$ be a radius of the  circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$.

Thus, $z\leq y$, $R\leq1$ and we need to prove that $$BC\cdot AB\leq 2CM$$ or
$$\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2-z^2}\geq xz$$ or
$$2x^2+2y^2-z^2\geq x^2z^2.$$
Now, since $R=\frac{xyz}{4S_{\Delta ABC}}$, we obtain
$$\frac{xyz}{4S_{\Delta ABC}}\leq1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^2y^2-x^4)\geq x^2y^2z^2$$ or
$$z^2(2x^2+2y^2-z^2)\geq(x^2-y^2)^2+x^2y^2z^2.$$
If $z=0$ then $a=b$, which gives that our inequality is true.

While for $z\neq0$ we obtain:
$$2x^2+2y^2-z^2\geq\frac{(x^2-y^2)^2}{z^2}+x^2y^2\geq x^2z^2$$
and we are done!

Comment: How does |a|≤1,|b|≤1,|c|≤1 imply that R≤1? If a,b,c are almost colinear won't the Circumradius be very large?

Comment: @Aaditya Vaze By the given $a$, $b$ and $c$ placed inside the disc  $x^2+y^2\leq1.$

Comment: If a=(1,0), b=(-1,0) and c=(0,0.1) then R=5.155>1

Comment: @Aaditya Vaze You are right. It's nothing. I have a proof for $x+y\leq\sqrt{12}$. I don't see what happens for $\sqrt{12}<x+y<4.$ Maybe in this case there is a counterexample.

Comment: The inequality to be proved stands correct for this case and numerous computations I have done, but I haven't been able to prove it.